# How use a function from another file in react native

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

I need to use a function from file Home.js , in file Settings.js. I'm using functional components. I need to use the function  `const getTempBucketData = () => {}` that fetch data from Home.js, in Settings.js.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Home.js
export const getTempBucketData = () => {}

// Settings.js
import { getTempBucketData } from './Home';

const data = getTempBucketData();
```

Comment: My function getTempBucketData is inside of export default Home. When i put the export before const it shows "Modifiers cannot appear here."

Comment: I think that's because you are using default keyword,
Remove default or const.
Edit: if you feel my answer is right, Mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

you should write the export keyword with the required function and then simply import that particular function using the import
for instance:

```js
    // in Settings.js file
     export const funcName = () => {
           //logic here 
    }
    //in Home.js file
    import {funcName } from './appropriatePath/Settings'
```

now you can use this funcName in this file legally